In contemporary neuropsychology, are disorders considered inherently differentiated brain phenomena, or heuristically segmented etiologies?
I mean, consider disorders like: bipolar disorder, schizophrenia/psychosis, and ADHD.
Does contemporary research suggest that these conditions are discrete typological differences from a "normal" brain, in the way that say, anemia is a markedly differentiated collection of symptoms due to precise physiological differences with a cascade of downstream functional differences, with a high degree of regularity?
Or does contemporary research suggest that the classification of disorders is a pragmatic diagnostic technique to assess which aspects of brain function may be affected and what kinds of interventions may be most applicable, but not because those symptoms have a recurrent, unifying cause?
One thing that these questions bear on is, how accurate is it to say that someone "has bipolar disorder" or "is bipolar"? Hypothetically, if technology enabled it, could we look at their brain, or DNA, and see the bipolar mechanism unambiguously? Or is there actually a lot more variation in why people might exhibit characteristics described by a diagnostic manual, and bipolarity might be a behavioral phenomenon, but not a static or inherent attribute of a person?
